# "Error splicing file: Input/output error"

Tags: filesystem

I recently obtained a Seagate Expansion 3TB external harddrive. I'm trying to copy over all of my stuff to prepare for reformatting and installing a new OS. A handful of my mp3s did not transfer when I was doing my music folder. I checked them after the fact and the ORIGINAL files became corrupted somehow. I am certain of at least a few that were not corrupted in anyway before doing this. Every now and then during my transfer I got

```
There was an error copying the file into /media/***/Seagate Expansion Drive.
Error splicing file: Input/output error
```

Each of these files that I check after are corrupted at some point in the duration and will not play. Why did this happen and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: This error indicates a problem with the storage media. Either a bad drive, or a filesystem problem. Are you sure that corrupted MP3's was work fine bedore copying? Also you can try to use `gnome-disk` utility to check your drive

Comment: One of my mp3's was corrupted for sure and in a very strange way. I loaded it into the movies media player and it froze around 12 seconds. So next time I loaded it I skipped to around 15 seconds and it somehow had fused with another song in my library, then after a few seconds went back to normal. I know that the song was not corrupted because I copied it to my phone some time ago and it's totally fine on there.

Comment: Ubuntu says for my main harddrive on the laptop "DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON (32° C / 90° F)". That's a relief that I got my external recently then. I wonder if installing a different OS will solve anything or is this disk pretty much screwed no matter what?

Answer (score 6):

Got this error too when copying data from my new dashcam.
Reason: I had accidentally connected the device to the USB 3.0 port.
After I connected the device to the USB 2.0 port, copying went well.

Comment: Why doesn't it work with USB 3.0?

Comment: Yeah there needs to be an explanation on this highly voted answer. USB 3.0 is backwards compatible with USB 2.0, so why didn't the USB 3.0 port work?

Comment: I too have an external hard drive that works on a USB 2.0 port but not on a USB 3.0, which seems to be underpowered.

Answer (score 3):

This normally means that your drive is failing or near-failing state. You should consider backup all your data and replace the drive. It could also happen with a corrupted file system, in which case a fsck while unmounted may be helpful. If after you repair the file system the drive continues failing then it's an imminent hardware failure.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more storage, or external devices connected you can try unplugging a few and try again. There seem to be some bugs with multiple hardware devices connected and when copying big files from one to the other. It can also indicate a bad drive or corrupt file though.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when moving an encrypted external disk (Veracrypt/NTFS) between Windows and Ubuntu, I had initially checked it working and then got this error the next day.

For me it was due to not properly unmounting the disk, I was able to resolve by returning to the windows machine and properly unmounting and then coming back to my Ubuntu box.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this error pop up when I tried backing up an encrypted mp3 file, effectively not having permission to copy/paste. After hitting skip to all, a file is created but it is relegated to an empty .txt file.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error on a D-Link ShareCenter NAS, with an SMB 1.0 mount. The solution for me was to add `cache=none,rsize=16384` to the `fstab` mount options, as described [here](https://forum.rclone.org/t/problem-with-copy-from-samba-share/3173/14).